# Overlap between a Schengen type C visa and a long-stay (type D) visa

Tags: schengen

Recently I have been issued a tourism Schengen visa to France valid until end of October. Also I applied for a student visa to Italy for a master's program that starts in September. It seems there will be overlapping weeks between the two visas yet they are of different types (one is type C the other is type D).

Would that cause a problem and force me to cancel one visa or the other?

Comment: That's not quite a duplicate, the second visa is a type D visa (i.e. not really a Schengen visa at all).

Comment: There is no reason it should be a problem. The type D visa grants you more extensive rights, the earlier Schengen visa should become irrelevant after that. Do check if there are special conditions for student visas in Italy, some countries require you to register, do a medical check-up or complete some other formalities within a certain time of entering the country. If you enter the Schengen area on your French visa, you want to make sure you go to Italy in time to complete these formalities.

Comment: @Relaxed but the requirements are presumably to be completed within a certain time after entering Italy, so there is no such thing as needing to get to Italy "in time."

Comment: @phoog That's one of the things that's been nagging me for a long time. Formally, I don't know Italian law (don't even know if there is something like that in Italy) but I strongly suspect you're right. But practically, what happens if you show up with an entry stamp long in the past? Would the delay run from the start of the second visa? Do you have to show when you actually entered the country? So what I meant is getting in Italy for that question not to be an issue at all, if possible.